# How would I make changes to all the items in the array from a given item?

Tags: python

For example, if I had a list of names :

```
list_of_name = [ 'James','Frank','Sam','Sara','Joe' ]
```

How would I make changes to only the items after the item I want in Python.
So for example for all the names after Sam, I wanted to change the other names to Sam. The solution would look like this :

```
list_of_name = [ 'James','Frank','Sam','Sam','Sam' ]
```

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something along the following lines:

```
def func(lst, val):
    try:
        i = lst.index(val)
        lst[i:] = [val] * (len(lst) - i)
    except ValueError:
        pass

>>> list_of_name = [ 'James','Frank','Sam','Sara','Joe' ]
>>> func(list_of_name, 'Sam')
>>> list_of_name
['James', 'Frank', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam']
```

And if you are into some Python >= 3.8 named-assignment kungfu, you can do this =)

```
def func(lst, val):
    t = None
    lst[:] = [t := x if t != val else t for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find first the index of your wanted value and than change all the elements to you wanted value if their index is grather than the index of the wanted value:

```
list_of_name = [ 'James','Frank','Sam','Sara','Joe' ]
wanted_name = 'Sam'
idx = list_of_name.index('Sam')

list_of_name = [wanted_name  if i > idx else n for i, n in enumerate(list_of_name)]
list_of_name
```

output:

```
['James', 'Frank', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Sam']
```

Answer (score 0):

somewhat brutish but

```
for i in range(list_of_name.index("Sam"),len(list_of_name)):
   list_of_name[i]="Sam"
```

should do it